# Pandas Get a list of index from dataframe.loc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have looked through various sites and SO posts.Seems easy but somehow i am stuck with this.I am using

```
print frame.loc[(frame['RR'].str.contains("^[^123]", na=False)), 'RR'].isin(series1.str.slice(1))
```

to get

```
3     True
4    False
8    False
Name: RR, dtype: bool
```

Now,somehow i want the `indexes` only so that i can use that in `dataframe.drop`. Basically all the indexes where value is `True` , i have to grab `indexes` and `drop` them.Is there any other way as well without using `indexes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing two conditions on the same column so these can be combined (and negated):

```
frame[~((frame['RR'].str.contains("^[^123]", na=False)) & (frame['RR'].isin(series1.str.slice(1))))]
```

Here, after `~` operator, it checks whether a particular row satisfies both conditions - same as the boolean array you get in the end. With `~`, you turn True's to False's and False's to True's. Finally, `frame[condition]` returns the rows that satisfy the final condition with boolean indexing.

In a more readable format:

```
condition1 = frame['RR'].str.contains("^[^123]", na=False)
condition2 = frame['RR'].isin(series1.str.slice(1))
frame[~(condition1 & condition2)]
```

As an alternative (requires 0.18.0), you can get the indices of the True elements with:

```
frame.loc[(frame['RR'].str.contains("^[^123]", na=False)), 'RR'].isin(series1.str.slice(1))[lambda df: df].index
```

Comment: So which of the two would be faster considering frames would have a million entries

Comment: Most probably the first one. The second one first returns another frame and tests another condition just to give the indices - which then need to be used in another method (drop). I've tested on a small dataframe and the first one is 2x faster (without considering the drop part). Of course this may change based on the entries you have in series1, in frame['RR'], etc.

Comment: Cool!!! thanx a lot!!! can you share some good resource on `pandas`? the info is all splattered across....

Comment: You are welcome. My main source are Q&A's here and the [docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/). There is also Wes McKinney's [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) (although a little dates, a new edition is about to come). Lastly, Tom Augspurger's [Modern Pandas series](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) is quite nice.